# Thread killed when application is backgrounded?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++14, fuse

I'm developing a fuse filesystem and before calling `fuse_main_real()` I'm starting a `std::thread` in a class instance to do some background work.

```
this->t_receive = new std::thread([this] { this->receive(); });
```

However, it seems like `fuse_main_real()` kills this thread when going into background.
If I start the program with the `-f` option, which tells fuse to stay in the foreground, the problem does not occur and the thread survives.

I'm not sure what fuse does to go into background.

How do I make my thread survive being backgrounded?

---

Edit: Here's a basic example that exposes the problem:

```
#define FUSE_USE_VERSION 30

#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

#include <fuse.h>

static void thread_method()
{
        while (true)
        {
                std::cout << "test" << std::endl;
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        }
}

struct testop : fuse_operations
{ };

static struct testop ops;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        std::thread(thread_method).detach();
        fuse_main_real(argc, argv, &ops, sizeof(fuse_operations), NULL);
}
```

Compile with

```
g++ -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 `pkg-config --cflags fuse` -lfuse -lpthread -std=c++14 -o test.o test.cpp
```

Command that works (repeatedly says "test"):

```
./test.o -f /home/test/testmountpoint
```

Command that doesn't work and shows the problem (says "test" once):

```
./test.o /home/test/testmountpoint
```

Comment: That question seems incomplete...

Comment: Unrelated: Why dynamically allocate a `thread`? Seems an odd and possibly reckless choice.

Comment: I'm guessing that fuse uses "fork and exit" to daemonize.  This causes a new background process to be created, and the original main process to terminate, along with it's threads.  Ideally you would create the thread you need in the child process after the fork has happened.  Unfortunately I don't know enough about the internals of fuse to know how to do this.

Comment: I think msandiford is right. Daemonization is usually done by fork-then-exit steps. Check if your thread is still alive in the child process.

Comment: @Phil1970 I've added an example.

Comment: A little bit of googling suggests that you should create the thread in the `.init` function specified in `fuse_operations` passed to `fuse_main_real`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [libfuse wiki](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/wiki/FAQ#how-should-threads-be-started) says that

> Miscellaneous threads should be started from the init() method. Threads started before fuse_main() will exit when the process goes into the background.